# it says "no thumbnail" after the image is saved in to gallery- android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gallery, android-bitmap

I have on Click method to save the image in to gallery . After i click "save" the folder is created in gallery , but when i go in to gallery it says " no thumbnail " ...
here is my code:

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/PhotoEditor ");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    if (sb != null) {
                        sb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(ShowPhotoActivity.this,"Your image is saved to gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
                // immediately available to the user.
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ShowPhotoActivity.this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you log "file.toString()" and see what you get? You might need to pass the absolute path: file.getAbsolutePath() as opposed to calling file.toString() but its hard to diagnose. Have you used a file manager app to confirm that the jpg really does exist after you've closed the stream?

Comment: Yes,I think it doesn't get the bitmap. Can you show me a code or something ?